# Native Apple Pay Timeout

Tags: timeout, applepay

I am implementing Apple Pay in our iOS Native app.

I create PKPaymentRequest object, and display the Apple Pay payment sheet successfully.
After I authorize it by Touch ID, I can get the payment token.

After I send this token to payment provider, it will shows [processing] on payment sheet.
All things work well.

But when the server-side spend longer than 30 seconds,
it will show error dialogue on payment sheet.

[image: image description here]

My question is that is there a timeout time for Token payment process? If Yes, is it 30 seconds?

Lu

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

> The onpaymentauthorized function must complete the payment and respond by calling completePayment before the 30 second timeout, after which a message appears stating that the payment could not be completed.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaysession/1778020-onpaymentauthorized